# Grails one-to-many relationship failing to create link back to parent when using a LazyList

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

I have a requirement to persist the parent and children of a one-to-many relationship in one go - the domain objects in question are `Project` and `ProductLineItem` (a `Project` has many `ProductLineItem`s).

I've created a page where a user can add one or more rows to a 'products' table, and I want each row to be persisted as a new `ProductLineItem` (owned by the `Project`) when a user submits the form.

Saving the domain objects for the first time works great, however when I try to update the same set of objects (via the update page) I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException in the controller when doing

```
projectInstance.properties = params
```

I can fix this by declaring the `productLineItems` collection in `Project` like this -

```
Collection<ProductLineItem> productLineItems = ListUtils.lazyList(new ArrayList(), {new ProductLineItem()} as org.apache.commons.collections.Factory)
```

however for some reason this prevents the `ProductLineItem.project` property from being populated when I do the initial save.

I'm using Grails 2.2.2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that declaring the collection as a bag seems to prevent Grails setting up the foreign key constraint.

By changing

```
Collection<ProductLineItem> productLineItems = ListUtils.lazyList(new ArrayList(), {new ProductLineItem()} as org.apache.commons.collections.Factory)
```

to

```
List<ProductLineItem> productLineItems = ListUtils.lazyList(new ArrayList(), {new ProductLineItem()} as org.apache.commons.collections.Factory)
```

I was able to fix the problem.

EDIT:

For what it's worth, I didn't want to use a list (I always seem to run into issues with 'gaps' appearing when using lists for one-to-many relationship collections), so I kept fiddling around with my code.

If I declare the bag like this:

```
Collection<ProductLineItem> productLineItems = ListUtils.lazyList(new ArrayList(), {new ProductLineItem()} as org.apache.commons.collections.Factory)
```

then the reference to the parent is not set inside the child entity. However, if I declare the bag like this:

```
Collection productLineItems
```

then it works! And the collection auto-expands too!

Still testing my code, but it's looking good so far.